# How can I recieve data over UDP on embedded device

Tags: c++, c, udp, stm32, mbed

currently I am working on a UDP-Client Script for a Mbed Project. I work with the B-L475E-IOT01A development board and want to recieve data from another network device.

The sending side (on another device) works. I tested it with a python script on my computer.

I have the following problem: I can establish conection to the network and I can initialize a UDP socket with the `open()` function.
My problem is, that if I try to `bind()` the socket to either a port or a socket address I get the `nsapi_error_t` code `-3002`, which means "unsopported functionality".
Here is the code:

```
#include "UDPSocket.h"
#include "mbed.h"

const char SSID[] = "";
const char password[] = "";
const uint16_t Port = 37020;

UDPSocket socket;
WiFiInterface *wifi;
BufferedSerial pc(USBTX, USBRX, 115200);

int main() {
  pc.set_format(8, SerialBase::None, 1);

  wifi = WiFiInterface::get_default_instance();
  if (!wifi) {
    printf("ERROR: No WiFiInterface found.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  printf("\nConnecting to %s...\n", SSID);
  int ret = wifi->connect(SSID, password, NSAPI_SECURITY_WPA2);
  if (ret != 0) {
    printf("\nConnection error: %d\n", ret);
    return -1;
  }

  SocketAddress a;
  wifi->get_ip_address(&a);
  printf("IP: %s\n", a.get_ip_address());

  int returnable = 1;
  while (returnable != 0) {
    returnable = socket.open(wifi);
    printf("%d\r\n", returnable);
    wait_us(500000);
  }

  returnable = 1;
  while (returnable != 0) {
    returnable = socket.bind(Port);
    printf("%d\r\n", returnable);
    wait_us(500000);
  }

  while (1) {
    char message[500];
    int n = socket.recv(&message, sizeof(message));
    printf("%d\r\n", n);
    printf("%s", message);
    wait_us(100000);
  }
  wifi->disconnect();

  printf("\nDone\n");
}
```

I deleted the wifi data for safaty reasons. Here is the output:

```
Connecting to ...
IP: 192.168.178.25
0
-3002
```

My question is, why I cant bind my board to a specific port. Do you have any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: C or C++? Please tag the language you are actually using. C and C++ have some overlap, but they are different distinct languages

Comment: mbed uses both languages but the main language is C++

Comment: do you compile the code you posted as C or as C++ ?

Comment: I compile it as C++ code

Answer (score 0):

MBED declares `socket.bind` as `bind (const Host &me)`. The argument is not a port number, but a `Host` instance. Change it to

```
sock.bind(Host(IpAddr(), port));
```

Comment: On deprecated versions `bind()` is declared like you mentioned, but in the mbed 6 version I got this two functions to work with: `nsapi_error_t bind(const SocketAddress &address)` or `nsapi_error_t bind(uint16_t port)`. The last function calls the first fuction with the ip address `0.0.0.0`. I tried both but none of them worked that way I thought.